# Twelve REST API doesn't work on mobile browsers?

Tags: node.js, api, mobile, browser

I've deployed a site to Netlify (https://quizzical-nightingale-64ead9.netlify.app/) and I use a node server to make an axios request to the Twelve API (https://rapidapi.com/twelvedata/api/twelve-data1)

There's a limit of 12 requests per minute for the API fyi.

It works fine on Chrome on my desktop but doesn't work on any mobile browser (brave, duckduckgo, Chrome).

I don't believe it's specific to Twelve because I had a similar experience with Finnhub API. I think it has to do with the fact it's a mobile browser. CORS maybe?

Here's my server/index.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
const axios = require('axios').default;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://twelve-data1.p.rapidapi.com/price',
  params: { symbol: 'GME', format: 'json', outputsize: '30' },
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'twelve-data1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.TWELVE_API_KEY,
  },
};

app.get('/gme_quote', (req, res) => {
  axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      const price = response.data.price;
      res.send(price);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

And here's my react component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function GameStop() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/gme_quote')
      .then((response) => {
        let price = response.data.toFixed(2);
        setPrice(price);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <h1 className="text-red-500 text-6xl font-black">GME</h1>
      <h1 className="text-white text-7xl md:text-8xl mt-10 md:mt-20">
        ${price}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this on my mobile device (safari) and it's working absolutely fine for me.

[Twelve Data API](https://rapidapi.com/twelvedata/api/twelve-data1/pricing) has a rate limit of 8 requests per minute and 800 total requests per day. Probably you have hit the rate limit that's why it was not working.